# Automate mail merge without VB?

Tags: java, oracle, email, ms-word, office-automation

Is there a way to automate mail merge without using Visual Basic? I don't know how to code in visual basic

I'm currently exporting data from an Oracle 10G database to an Excel file then filling fields in a word doc using mail merge.

Is there a way to improve this process? Maybe using Java?

Comment: Office exposes a COM automation interface that can be called from any language that can speak COM.

Comment: I've never heard of COM, can you explain this to me more?

Comment: Its a mechanism that allows you to control an application from another language E.g. [How to automate Microsoft Word to perform Mail Merge from Visual C#](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/301659) - (This is more difficult from Java last I checked)

Answer (score 0):

To perform Microsoft Word(DOCX/DOC) Mail Merge using Java, [Aspose.Words Cloud SDK for Java](https://github.com/aspose-words-cloud/aspose-words-cloud-java) is an option. Aspose.Words REST API also offers SDKs of all popular languages. It is paid API but also provides monthly free credits.

sample code:

```
WordsApi wordsApi = new WordsApi(new ApiClient());
ApiClient client = wordsApi.getApiClient();
// Get App Key and App SID from https://dashboard.aspose.cloud/
client.setAppKey("[APPKEY]").setAppSid("[AppSID]);


try {
    
    Path file = Paths.get("C:/Temp/SampleMailMergeTemplate.docx");
    Path fdata = Paths.get("C:/Temp/SampleMailMergeTemplateData.txt");
    
    ExecuteMailMergeOnlineRequest request = new ExecuteMailMergeOnlineRequest(Files.readAllBytes(file), Files.readAllBytes(fdata), null, null, null);

    File result = wordsApi.executeMailMergeOnline(request);
    
    File dest = new File("C:/Temp/MailMerge_out.docx");
    Files.copy(result.toPath(), dest.toPath(), java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);

} catch (
        Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

P.S: I am working as Support Developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.